# Persistence of Docker Data Containers

Tags: docker

I'm in the process of turning my application servers into Docker Containers. As the application servers persist their configuration in XML files, I have created and started a Data Container named "data" which mounts the application server configuration folder. Then I have started the container with:

```
docker run --rm -h server-v01 --name server-v01 --volumes-from data rhel/server-dc
```

I have applied some changes to the configuration and then issued a "docker stop" command on both containers.
When I have restarted the containers, I can see that configuration changes have not been persisted by the Data Container.
Is it the correct behaviour of Data Containers ? I'd need to make all changes in the Data Container persistent automatically. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue could be in the `--rm` flag. If you have added this option when running the Data Container, it will be removed once you stop this container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have started the Data Container with the --rm flag. However trying to restart it without the --rm option causes "Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "data" is already in use by container b1a535a9eae0. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name."

Comment: How are you restarting the containers? Using the `docker restart` command or running `docker stop` and `docker run` commands? Note that the `docker run` command will create a new container.

Comment: I have managed to restart the data container with "docker start b1a535a9eae0". It works and changes in configuration are preserved. Is it a safe way to handle data created by Containers, or I could accidentally lose data in case the container crashes? Thanks

Comment: If the container is removed you will lose all your data. If you want to preserve the data, you can mount a volume from your Data Container to your local machine that contains the important data. Also, you can create a script that just make a backup of the data in the container into you local machine, e.g.:`$ docker run --rm --volumes-from data -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar <path-to-the-data-folder>` 
You can find more information about that in the [https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/](docker guide).